# How to use modal box from different view page to work inside on click function

Tags: javascript, cakephp-1.3

```
$(".event_over_time").click(function()
 {  
//i want the modal box to be opening up on this click function here
 });
```

the modal box opens up on click in a different page in my site i want the same modal box to open up for the click function on a different page in my website basically a shortcut to the view modal box through the click function

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure your modal HTML code is in the footer so that it's loaded on all pages of your website. Next you have to give the modal an id so that we can use that in the click function (I used `#modal` in the example).

Since you're using jQuery you can use the function .fadeIn to transition the modal from `display: none;` to `display: block;`

The function will look something like this:

```
$('.event_over_time').on('click', function(e) {
    // Prevent default is used so you can also give the ID to a anchor tag without it executing the href
    e.preventDefault();
    // Here we use the jQuery .fadeIn function to show the modal.
    $('#modal').fadeIn(200);
});
```

if you want to make a function to close the modal you can do something like the code below and make sure there is a close button in the modal with the ID of `#closeModal`.

```
$('#closeModal').on('click', function(e) {
    // Prevent default is used so you can also give the ID to a anchor tag without it executing the href
    e.preventDefault();
    // Here we use the jQuery .fadeOut function to hide the modal again.
    $('#modal').fadeOut(200);
});
```